# How do I transfer this SQL statement into a LINQ query?

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I have this pretty easy SQL Statement and I want to get the same data using LINQ, but I can't seem to find the right way.

```
select A.AUFTRAGID,
       A.AUFTRAGNR, 
       A.GESELLSCHAFTID, 
       A.DEBITORID,
       A.DEBITOR_KOMMNR2,
       A.DEBITOR_TEILELIEFERNR, 
       D.DEPOTID, 
       D.DEPOTNUM, 
       D.MATCHCODE, 
       D.NAME, 
       D.KS_ID
from AUFTRAG A
join DEPOT D on D.DEPOTID = A.DEPOTID and D.VALID = 1 and D.KS_ID = 1
where A.AUFTRAGID in 
      (select AUFTRAGID from AUFTRAG_STATUS where VALID = 1 
           and CRTI = (select max(CRTI) from AUFTRAG_STATUS where AUFTRAGID = A.AUFTRAGID) 
           and [STATUS] = 9)
```

I can successfully join the tables [AUFTRAG] and [DEPOT], but when it comes to the last where clause I am not able to figure out how to get my data in LINQ.

I'm looking forward for your help.

UPDATE - This is what I have done so far:

```
var erfAuftr = (from auf in db.AUFTRAG
                join dep in (from dep in db.DEPOT
                             where dep.KS_ID == 1
                             select dep) on auf.DEPOTID equals dep.DEPOTID
                join a_s in
                     (from a_s in db.AUFTRAG_STATUS
                      group a_s by new
                      {
                           a_s.AUFTRAGID
                      } into grp
                      select new
                      {
                           AuftragId = grp.Key.AUFTRAGID,
                           Date = grp.Max(s => s.CRTI)
                      }) on auf.AUFTRAGID equals a_s.AuftragId                                   
                 select new
                 {
                      AuftragId = auf.AUFTRAGID,
                      AuftragNr = auf.AUFTRAGNR,
                      DebitorId = auf.DEBITORID,
                      KVNr = auf.DEBITOR_KOMMNR2,
                      TL = auf.DEBITOR_TEILELIEFERNR,
                      DepotId = dep.DEPOTID,
                      DepotNum = dep.DEPOTNUM,
                      DepotMatchcode = dep.MATCHCODE,
                      DepName = dep.NAME1,
                      WEDate = a_s.Date
                  });
```

But I am still missing how to check for [STATUS] = 9

Comment: Seems like all you need is to generate the linq first for the first join...Then filter it out with another query within linq for the where clauses.  Combine the results and you are good to go.

Comment: Please show what you've got so far

Comment: [SO] is not a code writing service. Show you working so far, and explain why it isn't working.

Comment: You are right about that. I hope the updated question is more understandable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got it working by using the following expression:

```
Date = grp.Where(g => g.CRTI == grp.Max(s => s.CRTI) && g.STATUS == 9).Max(s => s.CRTI)
```

Thank you for your help anyway!

Answer (score 1):

You can add filter as:

```
select new
{
    AuftragId = grp.Key.AUFTRAGID,
    Date = grp.Where(c=>c.STATUS == 9).Max(s => s.CRTI)
}) on auf.AUFTRAGID equals a_s.AuftragId
```

Comment: Unfortunately this is not what I want to achieve. Your query gets me the biggest date where STATUS = 9, but I only want the dates where the entries in [AUFTRAG_STATUS] have the biggest CRTI and the STATUS = 9. So if the STATUS is not 9 for the entry with the biggest CRTI it should not be shown.